# Textjoin with if(countif) function

Tags: excel, textjoin

I have some values in A1:G1 (a,a,b,c,c,d,d), they are all letters. and in H1, I try to get this result (acd). I want to join only the values that repeat twice ore more. So it should be omitted if there is a single value.

I wrote this formula : `=TEXTJOIN(,TRUE,IF(COUNTIF(AY4:BD4,"a")>1,"a",IF(COUNTIF(AY4:BD4,"b")>1,"b",IF(COUNTIF(AY4:BD4,"c")>1,"c",IF(COUNTIF(AY4:BD4,"d")>1,"d","")))))`

but it doesn't work. I am not sure if textjoin works this way. I'd be glad if anybody can give me a solution. thanks.

Note: if the values are like this (a,a,a,a,a,b,c), then the result should be (a).

Comment: what about `=IF(COUNTIF(AY4:BD4,"a")>1,"a","")&IF(COUNTIF(AY4:BD4,"b")>1,"b","")&IF(COUNTIF(AY4:BD4,"c")>1,"c","")&IF(COUNTIF(AY4:BD4,"d")>1,"d","")` ? Maybe TEXTJOIN is possible too, like this : `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(COUNTIF(AY4:BD4,"a")>1,"a",IF(COUNTIF(AY4:BD4,"b")>1,"b",IF(COUNTIF(AY4:BD4,"c")>1,"c",IF(COUNTIF(AY4:BD4,"d")>1,"d","")))))`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((COUNTIFS(A1:G1,A1:G1)>1)*(COLUMN(A1:G1)-COLUMN(A1)+1=MATCH(A1:G1,A1:G1,0)),A1:G1,""))
```

Being an array formula is needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=2,A1,"")
```

and copy across.  Then in **H1** enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A2:G2)
```

[image]

and in your second example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I'll go without helper cells since there is too much data.